# How are the Seven Purifications (satta-visuddhi) practiced in daily life?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, visuddhimagga, daily-life

What are the 7 Purifications in laymans terms and how is this practiced in daily life?

Comment: I noticed you've tagged this question with Theravada, so I assume you are only interested in this from a Theravada point of view (and not Mahayana)?

Comment: Not really. This is inclusive of any other branches but at least one answer from some one from the Theravada perspective.

Answer (score 4):

This book is focused only on this question:

- [The Seven Stages of Purification & The Insight Knowledges](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/bm7insight.pdf) by Ven. Matara Sri Nanarama

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Is it would have been better if you could have made a summary here. But any great pointer.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. Some people object when I give a link without totally answering the question. I found a source that I thought would provide the answer but did not have the time to read the whole source and summarize. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 4):

The only sutta that fully explains the seven purifications is Rathavinita Sutta. It explains in full the seven purifications (SAPTHA VISUDDHI) taught by the Buddha:
see [The Ratha-vinita Sutta: Relay Chariots  (MN 24; M.I,145)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.024.than.html).

The only place in the Canon where these 7 kinds of purification are mentioned is M. 24,, The Simile of the Stage-coach; There it is said that the real and ultimate goal does not consist in purification of morality, or of mind, or of view, etc., but in total deliverance and ceasing. Now, just as one mounts the first coach and travels to the second coach, then mounts the second coach and travels with it to the third coach, etc., in exactly the same way the goal of (I) the purification of morality (sila-visuddhi) is  (II) the purification of mind (citta-visuddhi) its goal: (III) the purification of view (ditthi-visuddhi) its goal: (IV) the purification by overcoming doubt kankhāvitarana-visuddhi its goal: (V) the purification by knowledge and vision of what is path and not-path (maggāmagga-ñānadassana-visuddhi) its goal: (VI) the purification by knowledge and vision of the path-progress  (patipadā-ñānadassana-visuddhi); its goal: (VII) the purification of knowledge and vision (ñānadassana-visuddhi) but the goal of this purification is deliverance freed from all clinging.

If you practice the first two of the seven purifications to the best of your ability, everything else will fall into place. The goal of  purification of morality (sila-visuddhi) is the purification of mind (citta-visuddhi).

The purification of mind (citta-visuddhi)  is towards cultivating a mind that does not to feel sorry, self-reproachful, or contrite for past conduct; regret or be conscience-stricken about a past action,  attitude,  etc. as one would repent after one’s thoughtless acts. This is eradicating mind-defiling defilements that lead to suffering.

This leads to  purification of view (ditthi-visuddhi); This is a difficult one as the idea that truth always triumphs over power is one of those pleasant falsehoods. This idea that ‘Truth Always Wins’ was first coined by the Hindus. Today the Buddha Dhamma is lost to the masses. what they call as ‘Buddhism’ is  ‘adhamma’ – a falsehood. Just compare todays views to the Sutta & Vinaya Pitaka, and you will find this out.

If you overcome this hurdle of purification of view (ditthi-visuddhi); its goal:
the purification by overcoming doubt (kankhāvitarana-visuddhi) – yet another big hurdle. So I wish you the best. If you are a person of humility, and always trust the original scriptures only, and makes this practice your one and only pastime you will succeed.