# What is the meaning of ditthi visuddhi?

Tags: theravada

The third visuddhi of the Satta Visuddhi is "ditthi visuddhi". But what is the exact meaning of it ?

Comment: Please add more context and preferably references to your question. See also related [*question.*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/how-are-the-seven-purifications-satta-visuddhi-practiced-in-daily-life)

Comment: I wonder what this purification of insight practically means: is it the further realisation of the 8th folded Path, i.c. samma ditthi ?

Comment: Yes, it means having reached the path (magga), not really further. Not purified, people are still not practicing on the path, Nyom. Only if there is samma ditthi, other sammas will be not actually miccha in the "training".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purificatiin of view:

> 'The divine eye is purified since it is a cause for Purification of View (diṭṭhi-visuddhi), owing to seeing passing away and reappearance of beings. One who sees only passing away and not reappearance assumes the annihilation view (uccheda-diṭṭhi); and one who sees only reappearance and not passing away assumes the view that new beings appear (nava-satta-pātubhava-diṭṭhi). But since one who sees both outstrips that twofold [false] view, that vision of his is therefore a cause for Purification of View. And the Buddha's sons see both of these.' (PsA 259; Vism 423)

[Wisdom and the Seventy-Three Kinds of Mundane and Supramundane Knowledge](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/nanadassana/wisdom_en.html#fn-113), given by Ven. Bhikkhu Ñāṇadassana

Answer (score 1):

The [Nyanatiloka Buddhist Dictionary](https://what-buddha-said.net/library/pdfs/Nyanatiloka_Buddhist_Dictionary.pdf) defines it as "purification of insight", though [this book on meditation](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/bm7insight.pdf) gets a lot more in depth on what that actually means in practice (look at chapter 3). I'm finding it difficult to summarize as it's a bit dense for a beginner like me, but you might be able to glean more meaning from it.